# How do I disable warning about external references in Kmail?

Tags: kmail

In Kmail, there is a big warning when an incoming Email message contains HTML:

> Note: This HTML message may contain external references to images etc.
>   For security/privacy reasons external references are not loaded. If
>   you trust the sender of this message then you can load the external
>   references for this message by clicking here.

How is it possible to disable this warning message?  Close to 100% of my incoming messages are HTML, I know about the potential security risks of HTML email, and I don't need this warning.

This option exists in the settings:

Open Kmail --> Menu Settings --> Menu Configure Kmail --> Security --> Tab Reading --> Set Prefer HTML to plain text and set Allow messages to load external references from the Internet...

[image]

But it has no effect when the setting is changed.  Has this been deactivated?

KDE Neon 18.04

KMail Version 5.12.3

KDE Frameworks 5.65.0

Qt 5.13.2 (built against 5.13.2)

The xcb windowing system

---

Note: The answer to "[How to disable warning about external references in Kmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/how-to-disable-warning-about-external-references-in-kmail)" (from 2015) is no longer working in newer versions of KMail.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the [older question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171793/how-to-disable-warning-about-external-references-in-kmail) now has three deleted non-answers all asking for an update to this issue, which seems to have come back around 2017.

Comment: Automatically rendering HTML would cause your KMail client to request embedded images in the message from the origin site, which would expose (at a minimum) your public IP address to the origin.  GNOME Evolution has a whitelist for this, so you can trust senders once and then always render HTML automatically for those whitelisted senders.  Does KMail not have the same feature?